# Chrome extension: Could not load javascript file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, tumblr

I have posted another question regarding my Chrome extension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303597/tumblr-dashboard-modifications-per-chrome-extension).
But I have one more question about extensions themselves. I only need a content script for the modification of the Tumblr-Dashboard, no background page or something else, right?

Here is the `manifest.json` file:

```js
{
    "name": "Tumblr - Tiled Dashboard",
    "version": "0.0.54",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This extension modifies the look of your Tumblr dashboard.",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon_16.png",
        "48": "images/icon_48.png",
        "128": "images/icon_128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "*://*.tumblr.com/dashboard" ],
            "css": [ "styles.css" ],
            "js": [ "jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "masonry.min.js", "code.js" ]
        }
    ],
    "homepage_url": "mypage",
    "author":  "myname"
}
```

To start, I ask if this is alright? I have read a lot about the `manifest.json` file and everything seems to work fine when I try out the extension locally. But when I pack the extension and upload it, there are two problems:

1. I cannot find the extension when I search for it
2. When I use the link to find the extension, and I want to install it (tried that on 2 different PCs), I get an error, telling me that the `jquery-2.1.3.min.js` file could not be loaded. I therefore changed the order of my JavaScript files to test if it was a problem related to the jQuery file, but having `masonry.min.js` as the first file in the array resulted in the same error.

Why does this happen? Is the `manifest.json` file ok? Do I need some special permissions?

**Edit:**
This is a screenshot of when I try to install the extension from the Chrome Web Store (where I also can't find it by search).

[image: Screenshot of when I try to install the package from the Web Store]

Comment: A screenshot of the error would be nice. And you say you don't get this error with your development, unpacked version?

Comment: I added a screenshot above (it's german, sorry). My unpacked/local extension works fine! Another thing to mention is, that I get the same message for the 'masonry.js', if I change the order in the manifest-file.

Comment: Looks like you packed it incorrectly. What's the structure inside the zip you uploaded? It should be both `manifest.json` and `.js` files in the root of the zip, not inside a folder inside a zip.

Comment: You were right, I put the manifest and the *.crx file into the ZIP-file, not the root of the extension!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took a look inside your extension's ZIP file before downloading it, and the result was the following:

[image: zip]

<sup>*Inspected using [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) by Rob Wu</sup>

The problem here, is that you've uploaded a packed CRX file inside of your ZIP file, instead of your extension source code. You should instead **upload a ZIP file containing your extension's root**. Since that you're including the `manifest.json` file, the Web Store doesn't notice anything wrong until you try to install the extension, because the manifest is well written, but when Chromes tries to access the files declared, it fails and returns an error, because those files do not exist.

Quoting from the upload page of the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard:

> **Uploading an item**:
>
> - Upload a **ZIP file of your item directory**, not a packaged CRX file.
> - Include a well-designed product icon in your manifest ([more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons)).
> - [Read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/) about creating and packaging apps.
> - Need more help? Check out the [Chrome Web Store developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/).

So, you should create a **ZIP** file of your extension's root directory, containing **all** the files of your extension. Your ZIP file should then look like the following:

[image]

Comment: Well thank you for helping me out and have a look at it, I marked your answer! I didn't think I needed the root of my extension but the created *.crx file instead. I have one last question: What is the purpose of this *.crx file if not sending it to the web-store?

Comment: @Eru Previously, it was possible to host an extension/app outside Web Store. For that, you needed a CRX. Now it's still possible in some limited circumstances, but for CWS you upload a plain ZIP that is processed into CRX by Google servers.

Comment: @Xan thank you for the explanation, I think that got me confused somehow.

Comment: @EruIluvatar Xan is right, and, by the way, a CRX file is nothing but a "cool" archive. It's not encrypted or something else, you can open a CRX file like any ZIP file with the default ZIP explorer you use, like WinRar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "*Could not load javascript file*" error, then I noticed that **my_custom_script.js** file was not builded in **dist** directory (I'm using **npm**). You can move it manually and try to reload plugin to check is this problem.

Solution to me was adding **new entry** to **webpack.config.js** like this:

```js
 entry: {
    'my_custom_script': './my_custom_script.js',
    'background': './background.js',
    'popup/popup': './popup/popup.js',
    'options/options': './options/options.js',
  },
```