# Cannot Install Chrome Extension with jQuery after Publishing to Google Web Store

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I wrote a Chrome extension that uses jQuery.  It is working correctly when it is running from a local unpacked folder during development.  But after I have published to the Google Web Store and try to install it to Chrome, I am getting the following error:

Getting error: Package is invalid. Details: 'Could not load javascript 'jquery-2.1.1.min.js' for content script.'

I have try both jQuery 1.11.x and 2.1.x and got the exact same error.  I stripped down the extension trying to isolate the problem.  The manifest.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "jQuery DOM",
    "version": "0.0.6",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Manipulate the DOM when the page is done loading",
    "browser_action": {
        "name": "Manipulate DOM",
        "icons": ["images/edit48.png"],
        "default_icon": "images/edit48.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-2.1.1.min.js", "content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

and the content script is very basic:

```
$("body").append('Test');
```

I spent countless hours Googling, trying to figure this out without success.  There are some post indicating it is possible to include jQuery in an extension, including the Google documentation.  But I was not able to resolve it.  Has anyone encounter this problem before and able to resolve it?  Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension: Could not load javascript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318623/chrome-extension-could-not-load-javascript-file)

Comment: Sorry, my question is a duplicate.  The answer from Xan is exactly what I needed.  StackOverflow really rocks!